# sailsjs: how do I reverse engineer an existing db into sails/waterline models?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I am a SailsJS noob.
I have an existing database (postgres) that I want to turn into models for SailsJS/Waterline. is there a method/tool/utility to do this automatically like the datasource.discoverSchema() method in LoopBack?

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-model-reverser

node-sails-model-reverser

Produces static Sails / Waterline models by reverse engineering existing databases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034779/how-to-generate-model-from-exists-database-in-sails-js/50527553#50527553

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently this is not a method in sails/waterline.

Comment: Would be nice to have this feature.